# Get Data From Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array with different amounts of data,
I want to replace the period contents of the array with the data I want for example:

- Data array from key 0 to 4 of the period must contain "`2010-10-10`".
- data array from key 5 to 10 period must contain "`2010-11-11`"

Condition: I need an array of data from 0-4, 5-9, 10-14 (multiples of 5)
The following data I have:

```
[
     {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "SUNARTA",
         "period":"",
     },
     {
         "id": "2",
         "name": "AAN",
         "period":"",
     },
     {
         "id": "3",
         "name": "MIKO",
         "period":"",
     },
     {
         "id": "4",
         "name": "NIKA",
         "period":"",
     },
     {
         "id": "5",
         "name": "LALA",
         "period":"",
     },
     {
         "id": "6",
         "name": "MMAAN",
         "period":"",
     },
    {
     "id": "7",
     "name": "NINA",
     "period":"",
 }
]
```

This is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  var datePeriod = new Date(req.body.start);
  var periode = datePeriod;

  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    datePeriod.setDate(datePeriod.getDate() + 1);
    element[i].periode = periode;

  } else {
    element[i].periode = periode;
  }
}
```

I want data should be:

```
[
 {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "SUNARTA",
     "period":"2010-10-10",
 },
 {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "AAN",
     "period":"2010-10-10",
 },
 {
     "id": "3",
     "name": "MIKO",
     "period":"2010-10-10",
 },
 {
     "id": "4",
     "name": "NIKA",
     "period":"2010-10-10",
 },
 {
     "id": "5",
     "name": "LALA",
     "period":"2010-10-10",
 },
 {
     "id": "6",
     "name": "MMAAN",
     "period":"2011-11-11",
 },
 {
     "id": "7",
     "name": "NINA",
     "period":"2011-11-11",
 },
 ]
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: "*Data array from key 0 to 4 of the period contains "2010-10-10"*" but not in the sample data you posted.

Comment: You could use `.map()` which take a predicate as argument (basically a function), so you can make a filter in it (if e.period === ?), then make your changes there.

Comment: @RobG yes because it was initially empty, and I will fill it in the conditions that will be created because the array data from data 0 - 4 are the same, 5-9 contents are different from data 0-4

Comment: @Izio map? Do you mean filter?

Comment: @evolutionxbox filter will return an array according to the filter like: `return all data which have...`, I was talking about operate on the array directly, with the map operator

Comment: @Andreas I've tried it, above my code

Comment: @Izio would a foreach be better suited?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Maybe, but if you take this option, please consider using basic `for` loop, since `.forEach()` have very bad perf's. Also, storing the `array.length` and not use it directly in the loop will increase perf's too

Comment: can you add the sample result you need as you did with the sample data? It's not fully clear what the result should look like.

Comment: @LelySuju—where does `req.body.start` come from? `i % 5 == 0` will increment every fifth date (to the same value), all others will not be modified.

Comment: @RobG req.body.start from input type html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to a solution. Your issue is that you're reinitialising *datePeriod* on each loop. You only need to do that once, then increment it on every 5th element. So move the initialisation outside the *for* loop (and tidy a few other things):

```js
var element = [{"id": "1","name": "SUNARTA","period": ""},
               {"id": "2","name": "AAN","period": ""},
               {"id": "3","name": "MIKO","period": ""},
               {"id": "4","name": "NIKA","period": ""},
               {"id": "5","name": "LALA","period": ""},
               {"id": "6","name": "MMAAN","period": ""},
               {"id": "7","name": "NINA","period": ""}];

// Helper to format the date
function formatDate(d) {
  return `${d.getFullYear()}-${('0'+d.getMonth()).slice(-2)}-${('0'+d.getDate()).slice(-2)}`;
}

// Initialise datePeriod outside the loop
var datePeriod = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  // This variable is unnecessary
  //var periode = datePeriod;

  // Increment datePeriod every 5th element
  // The else loop isn't necessary
  if (i && i % 5 == 0) {
    datePeriod.setDate(datePeriod.getDate() + 1);
  }
  element[i].period = formatDate(datePeriod);
}

console.log(element)
```

This creates just one Date object, so it will be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` and iterate through each object based on the index increment date after every 5 iteration and update the `period` property.

```js
const data = [ { "id": "1", "name": "SUNARTA", "period":"", }, { "id": "2", "name": "AAN", "period":"", }, { "id": "3", "name": "MIKO", "period":"", }, { "id": "4", "name": "NIKA", "period":"", }, { "id": "5", "name": "LALA", "period":"", }, { "id": "6", "name": "MMAAN","period":"", }, { "id": "7", "name": "NINA", "period":"", }],
    size = 5,
    startDate = '2010-10-10',
    result = data.map((o,i) => {
      let index = Math.floor(i/size);
      let period = i == 0 ? new Date(startDate) : 
      (date => (new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + index))))(new Date(startDate));
      period = period.toISOString().substring(0,10);
      return {...o, period};
    },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: *toISOString* returns the UTC date, so will be the wrong date depending on the host timezone offset.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the date with one day for every 5 items then you can do the following:

A function that takes a start date and a number (index of the array) and add days to the start date depending on the number:

```
function calcDate(startDate, i) {
  return formatDate(
    new Date(
      new Date(startDate).setDate(
        //add a day every 5 days
        startDate.getDate() + Math.floor(i / 5),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now create a variable holding the start date: `var date = new Date();`

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to map the array you have to create a new array where period is set with the result of the calculate date function passing in the start date and the index of the current item:

```
var result = data.map(function(d, i) {
  return Object.assign({}, d, {
    period: calcDate(date, i),
  });
});
```

Complete code:

```js
var data = [{"id":"1","name":"SUNARTA","period":""},{"id":"2","name":"AAN","period":""},{"id":"3","name":"MIKO","period":""},{"id":"4","name":"NIKA","period":""},{"id":"5","name":"LALA","period":""},{"id":"6","name":"MMAAN","period":""},{"id":"7","name":"NINA","period":""}];

function pad(num) {
  return ('000' + num).slice(-2);
}
function formatDate(date) {
  return [
    date.getFullYear(),
    pad(date.getMonth() + 1),
    pad(date.getDate()),
  ].join('-');
}
function calcDate(startDate, i) {
  return formatDate(
    new Date(
      new Date(startDate).setDate(
        //add a day every 5 days
        startDate.getDate() + Math.floor(i / 5),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
var date = new Date();
var result = data.map(function(d, i) {
  return Object.assign({}, d, {
    period: calcDate(date, i),
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: *toISOString* returns the UTC date, so will be the wrong date depending on the host timezone offset.